# Vue.js - What happens to content inside script tag if you use src="script.js" in Vue files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Intellij IDEA with Vue plugin to create an SPA. As most of my views are getting big, I decided to separate them in template/script/css files. But IDEA is having some problems in finding the components I'm declaring in the .js file, so I tried to do the following:

```
<script src="./component-name.js">
    import ComponentName from './ComponentName';

    export default {
        components: {
            ComponentName
        }
    }
</script>
```

With that, IDEA recognizes the components and offers autocomplete/go-to definitions and all the stuff it should. But I'm wondering if there are any downsides to that? I know having content inside a script tag when using src isn't recommended in pure HTML5, but is that a problem here? I'm guessing it's ignored by webpack as I haven't had any problem with my application.

Comment: Why leave the content in at all? If you're using the src attribute, everything should be in the file that's referenced. Are you duplicating the code inside the tag with the code in the referenced file?

Comment: I'm duplicating only the components declaration, simply because my IDE isn't recognizing them... I don't know why, as it can find all the variables and functions that are inside the referenced js.